# Is there any way of adding an abbreviation/shorthand/constant in place of a string in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I've got an `@IBDesignable` `UILabel` with `@IBInspectable` properties, one of which is the font name.

Having to type in long complex font names into the storyboard is tedious and error prone:

[image]

What I would like to do if possible is have constants in the code, such as:

```
let Text75Bold        = "NHaasGroteskTXStd-75Bd"
```

And for this to be visible in the Storyboard, i.e.:

[image]

Is this possible?

For reference the label code is:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontSize:CGFloat = 15.0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var tracking: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontName: String = Display75Bold {
        didSet {
            decorate()
        }
    }

....
```

Comment: I don't think that it is possible but If you used code anyways, why don't you set the font programatically? This way you can save it's name into a constant

Comment: I am setting all these things programmatically, however I also want to set them in the Storyboard to use the storyboard as a design tool. Randomly tweaking font sizes, types, spacing programmatically and then running the app to see what it looks like is time consuming and inefficient when that tweaking can be done in the storyboard to see the effects instantly.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry I missunderstood your description.. If that font name is a custom inspectable property than you can use a dictionary. The short version as key and the oroginal name as value

Comment: Are you sure the storyboard is going to be able to translate a dictionary key into its value and update its view accordingly?

Comment: That property could be a simple string and in it's setter you can update the label's font from a dictionary (that is not an inspectable property) using that string as a key

Comment: @kemkriszt if you want to add it as an answer I can accept it, if you collect points.

Comment: Have you tried adding an inspectable property of type `UIFont`? I don't know if it'll work but if it does you can then the font name from that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments you can have a dictionary (not inspectable) using short names as keys and long names as values and simple string as an inspectable property. In the setter of that property you can update the font using it as a key for that dictionary.